# Have window covered by others even when active in mint cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon, window-management

I recently switched to Linux Mint with Cinnamon as the desktop environment. I much prefer it over Compiz but there is one feature that I'm sorely missing, in Compiz you can set [window rules](http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching#line-94), and more specifically the `below` functionality that allows you have have a window basically the opposite of always on top.

I like to run a full screen terminal on one of my workspaces all the time, every so often I want to bring a window over top of the terminal and not have it dropped behind when I bring the terminal into focus.

Is there anyway I can achieve this behaviour in Cinnamon?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is not an actual Cinnamon feature but a way to achieve this behaviour in a Cinnamon environment: with the small utility `devilspie2`, version `v0.42` (because of the `scripts_window_focus` feature).

Currently, the official Linux Mint repositories contain version 0.39 only. So you need to download `devilspie2` directly from the maintainer http://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/ and build by yourself. It's easy and quick. You'll find build and install instructions in the file `INSTALL` of the downloaded tarball.

After installing create two files in the directory `~/.config/devilspie2` (default configuration assumed):

`devilspie2.lua` with the following contents:

---

`scripts_window_focus = {
   "myscript.lua"
}`

---

`myscript.lua` with the following contents:

---

`if (get_application_name() == "Terminal") then
   set_window_below();
end`

---

Then simply start `devilspie2` from your full screen terminal. And then just kill the running `devilspie2` by typing `Control-C` (or stop it by `Control-Z`). If you want the behaviour not only for your full screen terminal, but for *all* terminal windows then don't kill/stop but instead start `devilspie2 &` in background.

As long as `devilspie2` is running with the configuration given above, each window with the application name `Terminal` (like `gnome-terminal`) will be "set below" on focus. So, every time you click in your full screen terminal, you'll get the focus but the terminal is left below all other windows.

I'm sure you can make the solution even more comfortable and suitable to your specific needs (e.g. run and stop on startup). Refer to `devilspie2` docs (`README` file in the tarball).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set your window focus mode to "mouse". Go into cinnamon settings => Windows and then:

[image]

That will cause the window under the mouse to have focus without raising that window. If you want to write on your terminal, place the mouse over it and you can do so without raising it.

Personally, I also disable raise-on-click so that I need to click on the title bar or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click to raise a window but that's just me.

Comment: This doesn't really cover the UX I want. I found myself, from years of muscle memory, clicking on the terminal instead of just hovering it negating the effect, plus sometimes I need to copy/paste lines from the terminal to the window on top so that didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion though.